# Webform questionnaire with scoring and reports

Tags: views, webforms

I've created several long/multipage questionnaires with webform and I need to have a scoring/rating at the end with the results gathered in a report for the user (preferable in pdf). 
But there are no models available that add a scoring per option and/or per form component.

What would be the preferred way to achieve a score ?
Could this be done with Views or with the webform-conditions? or via webform_validation?

Any recommendation or direction is very appreciated as I'm bit stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create **charts** from the survey results of the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, there are 2 typical/popular alternatives to pick from:

- [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (used in about 400 sites), to display Webform results in a graphical manner using a charting library.
- [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) (used in about 220 sites), which integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform (created with the Webform module) to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data.

The Drupal 7 version of both modules, requires the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (dependency).